# Tumblr permalink page posts overlapping notes

Tags: html, css

I am new to building themes and just put this one together all on my own. My theme uses Masonry and my posts are floated on the index page, but I'm trying to style the permalink page and I can't figure out how to get the post notes underneath the post itself. Example [here](http://hzlx-theme.tumblr.com/post/145588023010/sjobergtommy-sunset-en-bild-jag-pl%C3%A5tade-en). I saw that this question was asked a couple of weeks ago ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397721/post-notes-slides-over-the-posts-in-tumblrs-permalink-page)) and the solution was to add `top: 100%;` to the permalink styles in the css, but I tried that and had no luck.

Here's the CSS for the posts (commented out parts are my attempts at fixing it)

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 259px;
    width: 830px;

}

.posts {
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #4e4e4e;
    /*
    {block:PermalinkPage}
    padding-right: auto;
    padding-left: auto;
    float: none;
    {/block:PermalinkPage}
    */
}

...

.permalinknotes {
top: 100%;
}

#container #notecontainer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: auto;

}

#container #notecontainer ol.notes {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* margin: 50; */
  padding-top: 50;
}

#container #notecontainer img.avatar {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    {block:Posts}
        <div class="posts">

            {block:Text}
                <div class="title">
                    {block:Title}
                        {Title}
                    {/block:Title}
                </div>
                {Body}
            {/block:Text}

            {block:Photo}

                {LinkOpenTag}
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                {LinkCloseTag}
                {block:Caption}
                    {Caption}
                {/block:Caption}


            {/block:Photo}

            {block:Panorama}
                {LinkOpenTag}
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                {LinkCloseTag}
                {block:Caption}
                    {Caption}
                {/block:Caption}
            {/block:Panorama}

            {block:Photoset}
                {Photoset}
                {block:Caption}
                    {Caption}
                {/block:Caption}
            {/block:Photoset}

            {block:Quote}
                <div class="quote">
                    "{Quote}"
                </div>
                <!--
                {block:Source} -->
                    <div class="quotesource">
                        {Source}
                    </div>
                <!--{/block:Source}
                -->
            {/block:Quote}

            {block:Link}
                <a href="{URL}" class="link" target="_blank" {Target}>
                    {Name}
                    {block:Thumbnail} <img src="{Thumbnail}"/> {/block:Thumbnail}
                </a>
                {block:Description}
                    {Description}
                {/block:Description}
            {/block:Link}

        <div class= "chat">
            {block:Chat}
                {block:Title}
                    {Title}
                {/block:Title}
                {block:Lines}
                    <li>
                        {block:Label}
                            {Label}
                        {/block:Label}
                        {Line}
                    </li>
                {/block:Lines}
            {/block:Chat}
        </div>

            {block:Video}
                {Video-400}
                {block:Caption}
                    {Caption}
                {/block:Caption}
            {/block:Video}

            {block:Audio}
                <div align="center">{AudioEmbed-250}</div>
                {block:Caption}
                    {Caption}
                {/block:Caption}
            {/block:Audio}

            {block:Answer}
                <div class="asker">
                    {Asker} asked:
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    {Question}
                </div>
                {Answer}
            {/block:Answer}

            <div class="permalinks" style="height: 15px; width: 341px; opacity: 0.5;">
                <div class="date">
                    <a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo} </a> &hearts; <a href="{Permalink}">{block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}</a>
                </div> 

                <div class="reblogs">
                    {block:RebloggedFrom}
                        {<a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentName}">via</a>} {<a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootName}">source</a>}
                    {/block:RebloggedFrom} &nbsp;
                    <div id="buttons">{LikeButton color="black" size="13"}</div>&nbsp;<div id="buttons">{ReblogButton color="black" size="13"}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tags">{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}<a href="{TagUrl}"> #{Tag}&nbsp;</a>{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}</div>
            </div>


            {block:PostNotes}
            <div class="permalinknotes">
                <div id="notecontainer">{PostNotes}</div>
            </div>
            {/block:PostNotes}



    {/block:Posts}

</div>
```

Comment: Probably more of a comment than an answer. I think you should move the permalink block to inside your post block, have it at the bottom. That way when masonry runs it will position all of the content relevant to the post inside the `.post` container. You won't need `top:100%` in the css. You may still have to do a little formatting but that will treat each post object in it's own right. See here: http://i.imgur.com/qDvfrrQ.png

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will give this a try!

Comment: It worked! Wow what a simple fix I overlooked. Thank you so much I appreciate the help! Just have to figure out how to center it now and mess with the margin. Thanks again stranger. :)

Comment: Can someone submit an answer if the issue is resolved?